# How can I change old record by new record on postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Here is my records.

```
SELECT * FROM items;

 id | show | status | user_id | name | note   | note_mod | test  | test_mod
----+------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------+----------
  1 | t    |      1 |         | Adam | aaa1   |          | test1 | 
  2 | f    |      2 |       1 | Adam | aaa1   | aaa2     | test1 | test_new1
  3 | t    |      1 |         | Tom  | blabla |          |       | 
  4 | f    |      2 |       3 | Tom  | blabla | baaa     |       | ayyyyyy
  5 | t    |      1 |         | Eva  |        |          |       | 
  6 | f    |      2 |       5 | Eva  |        | meow     |       |
```

I wanna change note,test 1 and 3 values from note_mod,test_mod 2 and 4 like this.

```
 id | show | status | user_id | name | note   | note_mod | test  | test_mod
----+------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------+----------
  1 | t    |      1 |         | Adam | aaa1   | aaa2     | test1 | test_new1
  2 | f    |      2 |       1 | Adam | aaa1   | aaa2     | test1 | test_new1
  3 | t    |      1 |         | Tom  | blabla | baaa     |       | ayyyyyy
  4 | f    |      2 |       3 | Tom  | blabla | baaa     |       | ayyyyyy
  5 | t    |      1 |         | Eva  |        | meow     |       | 
  6 | f    |      2 |       5 | Eva  |        | meow     |       |
```

id 2 user_id and id 1 is same, id 4 user_id and id 3 is same.

I know select new record only like this code.

```
SELECT new.* FROM items old, items new WHERE old.id = new.user_id AND old.id != new.id;

 id | show | status | user_id | name | note   | note_mod | test  | test_mod
----+------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------+----------
  2 | f    |      2 |       1 | Adam | aaa1   | aaa2     | test1 | test_new1
  4 | f    |      2 |       3 | Tom  | blabla | baaa     |       | ayyyyyy
  6 | f    |      2 |       5 | Eva  |        | meow     |       |
```

But I have no idea to write UPDATE method. Anyone knows?

P.S.

Thanks for reply GROX13

What I need to do is change value from another records.

if i run this code

```
UPDATE items
SET (note_mod, test_mod) = ('new1', 'test_new1') WHERE id = 1;
```

record will change like this you know.

```
 id | show | status | user_id | name | note   | note_mod | test  | test_mod
----+------+--------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------+----------
  1 | t    |      1 |         | Adam | aaa1   | new1     | test1 | test_new1
```

But that code need to change every string 'new1', 'new2', 'new3' bla bla bla...

I am looking for the code like this.

```
UPDATE items
SET old(note_mod, test_mod) = new(note_mod, test_mod) WHERE id = 1;
```

old is mean id 1's note_mod. new is mean id 2's note_mod.
but I dont know how to define old and new on UPDATE. Any ideas?

I wanna match them from user_id.
status = 1 mean user register account (example.com/create)
then user_id, note_mod, test_mod always null.
name is required. note, test is nullable.

status = 2 mean edit profile (example.com/1/edit)
then user_id set id automatically ($data -> user_id = $request -> id)

if user change profile, profile not change immediately.
profile can be change by my sql code only.

if user change note or test,
that set into note_mod or test_mod, not into note or test. ($data -> note_mod = $request -> note)
note, test, note_mod, test_mod is nullable.

Comment: Ok, you want to match them based on username. But how do you know which row needs to be updated and which row should be the source for this update? Is it the `show` field ? is it the difference in `id` ? Is it the `note_mod` being NULL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so if you only have four entries:

```
UPDATE items
SET (note_mod, test_mod) = ('new1', 'test_new1') WHERE id = 1;

UPDATE items
SET (note_mod, test_mod) = ('new2', 'test_new2') WHERE id = 3;
```

For your case I think this should work but have not tested:

```
UPDATE items SET (note_mod) = (note) WHERE note_mod IS NULL AND note IS NOT NULL;

UPDATE items SET (test_mod) = (test) WHERE test_mod IS NULL AND test IS NOT NULL;
```

I'll check and update answer.

Comment: Thanks for very fast reply. your code seems add string into column. But every value is not same as like as 'new1'. I wonder set (1.note_mod) = (2.note_mod)... is it possible?

Comment: Could you explain that in your question. I don't get what and when should be set?

Comment: I think you just need to elaborate on what you need to to. The above code by GROX13 will do what you needed in your question.

Comment: YESYESYESYES!!!!!!!!!! THAT'S WHAT I NEEDED!!!!!!!!!!!!! THANK YOU MY GOD!!!!!!!!!!! I <3 YOU ;)

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there when you wrote:

```
SELECT new.* FROM items old, items new WHERE old.id = new.user_id AND old.id != new.id;
```

---

(replacing {old,new} by {o,n}, because they are keywords)

```
UPDATE items o
SET note_mod = n note_mod
  , test_mod = n.test_mod
FROM items n
WHERE o.id = n.user_id
AND o.id <> n.id
-- avoid null updates:
-- AND (o.note_mod <> n.note_mod OR o.test_mod <> n.test_mod)
  ;
```